# Quartz scheduler exception while adding misfire-instruction to scheduler

Tags: xml, cron, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to attache a misfire instruction to a scheduler defined using the XML plug-in

(The job should run every minute, and if the job misfires it should do nothing and run the next job on schedule)

```
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>MyJob</name>
        <group>MyGroup</group>
        <description>My job description</description>
        <job-class>com.path.to.MyJobClass</job-class>     
    </job>

    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>JobCronTrigger</name>
            <description>
                bla bla
            </description>
            <job-name>MyJob</job-name>
            <job-group>MyGroup</job-group>
            <cron-expression>0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?</cron-expression>
            <misfire-instruction>MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING</misfire-instruction>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

I'm getting an XML validation exception with this message

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'time-zone'. One of 
'{"http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData":priority, 
"http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData":calendar-name, 
"http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData":job-data-map, 
"http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData":start-time, 
"http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData":start-time-seconds-in-future, 
"http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData":misfire-instruction, 
"http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData":cron-expression}'
is expected.
```

I've tried adding `<time-zone>UTC</time-zone` to the cron definition but I just got more validation errors.
Needless to say that when I removed

> MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING

everything worked fine. So how can I fix my XML ?

I'm using Quartz 2.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Quartz XSD](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/xml/job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd#L175) the `misfire-instruction` element must precede the `cron-expression` one.

And that is what the error message tells you. It mentions the `time-zone` element as this is the only valid element *after* `cron-expression`.